# How to get value/values of buttons created using twitter bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the following HTML code for button creation. I've applied the classes from bootstrap to these buttons.

```
<label class="help-block" for="xlInput">Monetization</label>
<div id="revsource" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
<button id="revenueSource" class="btn monibtn active" value="1" data-toggle="button" type="button">Advertise</button>
<button id="revenueSource" class="btn monibtn" value="2" data-toggle="button" type="button">License</button>
<div class="controls">
<input id="revenueSource1" type="hidden" 0="0" name="data[RevenueSource][revenue_source_id]" value="1,2">
</div>
</div>
```

Now what I want is the value or values of the buttons selected by user. Means if user selects button 1 then I want the concerned value of button 1. If he selects button 2 only then the concerned value of button 2 I should get and if user selects both the buttons then I should get the values of both buttons. For achieving this I tried following code but it didn't work. Can anyone please help me out in this thing? Thanks in advance.

```
$('.monibtn').click(function(){
            var selected = [];
            $('.monibtn').each(function(){
                if($('.monibtn').hasClass('active')) {
                    selected.push($(this).val());
                    $('#revenueSource1').val(selected);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: IDs must be unique. You have two elements with the same ID in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) along with the target selector `.monibtn.active`

```
$('.monibtn').click(function () {
    //get all .monibtn elements with class active and create an array with the value of those elements
    var selected = $('.monibtn.active').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    //assing the value of the selected array to the target element
    $('#revenueSource1').val(selected.join());
});
```

Comment: @NoobEditor it returns  a new jQuery object which contains the value returned by the callback function see http://api.jquery.com/map/